# Trying to write dynamic sql and export results to a text file

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I am trying to write some dynamic sql and export the results to a text file.  I saw some examples online about exporting the results of a query to a text file, so I tried to copy the concept and combine it with my dynamic sql.  The dynamic sql part works, but the part writing to a text file doesn't work.  Any thoughts?  This is for SQL Server 2008.

```
Declare @STARTDATE Varchar(30)
Declare @ENDDATE Varchar(30)
DECLARE @SQLQUERY Nvarchar(4000)

SET @STARTDATE = '2017-04-01'
SET @ENDDATE = '2018-04-30'

'bcp' + ' SELECT 'select top 1 '+(select [Source_Column_Name]) ' +
+' from data_mart_us.dbo.' + (select [Source_Table] )  +' where asofdate between '''+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@STARTDATE, 120)+  ''' and ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@ENDDATE, 120) + ''''
  FROM [RECONCILIATION].[dbo].DQ_CheckList_ADC
  where database_name like 'data_mart_us' + 'queryout C:\Contacts.txt -c -T''
```

Comment: Why do you say "the dynamic sql part works"?   The code you've posted above shouldn't do anything except maybe raise an error.   What are you seeing to make you say it works?

Comment: The dynamic SQL prints to the grid.  I want to save it to a text file, using pure SQL.

Comment: It prints what to a grid?   And what do you want to save to a text file?   Can you post a script that fully reproduces where you are at right now?   The code you posted in your question can't possibly be printing anything.  It's impossible to help with what you have posted right now.

Comment: The is no dymanic SQL and there is no printing to grid.   VTC

Comment: As it turns out, you can click 'Query' and 'SQLCMD Mode'.  Then enter one line at the top of the query: ':OUT C:\your_path_here\test.txt'.  That works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This following worked for me:

```
DECLARE @sqlQuery NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @filePath NVARCHAR(255);
SET @filePath = 'C:\Path\To\Your\File\output.txt';

SET @sqlQuery = 'SELECT * FROM YourTableName';

-- Create a temporary table to store the results
CREATE TABLE #TempResults (
    -- Define columns based on your query result structure
    Column1 INT,
    Column2 VARCHAR(50),
    -- Add more columns as needed
);

-- Execute the dynamic SQL and insert results into the temporary table
INSERT INTO #TempResults
EXEC sp_executesql @sqlQuery;

EXEC xp_cmdshell '''bcp "SELECT * FROM #TempResults" out "', @filePath, '" -c -T''';

DROP TABLE #TempResults;
```